# Want to create a menu in wordpress exactly likes http://www.bienvillecapital.com/

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a vertical menu exactly like http://www.bienvillecapital.com/. I have tried few themes having vertical menu and also tried SuperFly menu plugin to get the result. Can anyone help me to get this?

Thank you.

Comment: this QA is programming-specific. are you open to solutions that involve coding?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation bars are nothing more than HTML and CSS code aligned properly. I'm not really sure how well you know CSS and HTML, but this can be done with those, and understanding the concept is very direct. Please refer to this page for example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp